# Defining route links outside of app template in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular, angular2-routing

I was just wondering if it's bad practice to define angular2 app router links outside of the app; or if there is a better way of doing it.

In all of the angular2 documentation, it gives examples of routing, and it defines the links within the app template (see below).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Component Router</h1>
    <nav>
      <a [routerLink]="['CrisisCenter']">Crisis Center</a>
      <a [routerLink]="['Heroes']">Heroes</a>
    </nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@RouteConfig([
  {path:'/crisis-center', name: 'CrisisCenter', component: CrisisListComponent},
  {path:'/heroes',        name: 'Heroes',       component: HeroListComponent}
])
export class AppComponent { }
```

In that example, they define the links with `<a [routerLink]="['CrisisCenter']">Crisis Center</a>`.

But what if I did this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <a href="#/crisis-center">Crisis Center</a>
        </nav>

        <div>
            <my-app></my-app>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Would that work for navigation within the app?

The reason I want to keep them outside of the app, is because I have a lot of permission handling (hide/show) based on Symfony variables, so I'd rather manage the menus with that.

Answer (score 1):

That would be fine, but the main reason to use RouteConfig and router-outlet is because it loads that part of the page into router-outlet without refreshing the page. So, just know that if you use normal anchor tags, it will no longer be a SPA(single page application).

Comment: Yeah, but the way I am doing it wouldn't refresh the page either. If they click on the link with `href='#/crisis-center'`, it should pick up the url change and load the angular page in the router-outlet.

Comment: Angular 2 supports two styles of urls, `/crisis-center/` and `#/crisis-center/`. It's configurable via `LocationStrategy` providers: `PathLocationStrategy` and `HashLocationStrategy`. If you want to take advantage of that feature then [routerLink] would be the way to go. [More info](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#browser-url-styles)